# Expo : How can I fetch data from Django Rest Framework API?

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, fetch, expo

I'm using Expo 5.0.1.
I have an API which works fine.

Here is my entire App.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

const [data, setData] = useState([{title: "First title"}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.68:89/cards/', {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("Error is : ", error))
  }, [])

const renderData = (item) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <Text>{item.user}</Text>
      <Text>{item.is_suspended}</Text>
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  ) 
}

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <FlatList
      data = {data}
      renderItem={({item}) => {
        return renderData(item)
      }}
      keyExtractor={item => item.user}
      />      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Bold: {fontWeight: '600',},
  Red: {color: 'red'}, 
  px30: {fontSize: '20px',},
  view: {justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: '20px',},
})
```

I can't even get the error from my '.catch'.
Here is the error:
[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCAJz.png)

And here is when I put useEffect code into function app :
[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzpL.png)

Someone can help me with get data from Rest Api?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use React state hooks in functional components.
That's why you got that error.
Try this code instead.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
export default function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState([{title: "First title"}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.68:89/cards/', {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("Error is : ", error))
  }, [])

const renderData = ({item, index}) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <Text>{item.user}</Text>
      <Text>{item.is_suspended}</Text>
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  ) 
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <FlatList
      data = {data}
      renderItem={renderData}
      keyExtractor={(i, k) => k.toString()}
      />      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Bold: {fontWeight: '600',},
  Red: {color: 'red'}, 
  px30: {fontSize: '20px',},
  view: {justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: '20px',},
})
```

**EDIT**

I have noticed your styles are wrong too.
replace them with

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Bold: {fontWeight: 600,},
  Red: {color: 'red'}, 
  px30: {fontSize: 20,},
  view: {justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 20,},
})
```

React native doesn't accept the 'px' as a style